# Проблема с выводом категории каждой статьи

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Добрый день, начал изучать Kohana для подключения к БД использую драйвер ORM, проблема такая имеется две таблицы **category**, **articles** на главной статье вывожу все статьи и хочу вывести категорию каждой статьи,

Таблица **category** (id, name), таблица **articles** (id, category_id, date, name, content)

```
protected $_has_many = array(
   'cat' => array(
   'model' => 'category',
   'foreign_key' => 'category_id',
   ),
);

$article = ORM::factory('article')->find_all();
$category = $article->cat->find_all
```

Что я делаю неправильно заранее спасибо

Comment: а я что-то в логике запутался... судя по структуре таблиц у вас не has_many, а belongs_to должен быть...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы реализовал как то так...:

**Model**

```
class Model_Article extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'category' => array(
            'model' => 'category',
            'foreign_key' => 'category_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function action_index(){
    $articles = ORM::factory('article')
                ->with('category')
                ->find_all();
}
```

**View**

```
foreach ($articles as $article){
    echo $article->category->id.' - '.$article->category->name;
}
```